# Comparing 2 variables in SQL stored procedure where 1 of them could be NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 variables and either one of them could be NULL. I need to do something if those 2 variables are not equal. If one of them is NULL and other one is valid, it should pass too. If both are NULL, then it should not pass.

This is what I used to have:

```
if (@newValue != @oldValue) --this doesn't work if one of them is NULL
```

Here's my current solution:

```
if (@newValue != @oldValue 
    OR (@newValue IS NULL AND @oldValue IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (@newValue IS NOT NULL AND @oldValue IS NULL))
```

Is there a better way to do this? I couldn't find similar question, but if this has been answered previously, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could also coalesce the null value into some *default* value that would never appear otherwise.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: I thought about that, but it's being used in other parts of the proc where it needs to be NULL.

Comment: What datatype are the variables? And is there a value that could never actually occur?

Comment: No, I meant just coalesce the values when you compare them..  Such as `if (COALESCE(@newValue, -1) != COALESCE(@oldValue, -1)`

Comment: Actually, what if both of them are NULL?

Comment: @srutzky: In my case, they are `char(5)`, but I was looking for a generic solution. If both are NULL, then it shouldn't pass.

Comment: `IF EXISTS (SELECT @var1 EXCEPT SELECT @var2) PRINT 'different'`

Comment: I removed my answer as I could not find anything more appropriate than what @MartinSmith posted directly above (i.e. using the `EXCEPT`), and the fact that this is a duplicate.